# Install Wine applications for multiple users

Tags: wine, multi-user

How to install Wine 1.8 in Ubuntu 16.04 and run Windows applications for multiple users, including standard users who also can use the same Windows applications.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are specifying 1.8 rather than the most recent version of wine?  The most recent version is 1.9.

Comment: the most stable version is 1.8.4 and 1.9.17 is development version.... I want solution for the stable version... have you tried multi user on 1.9.x  ?